# Cant select a column by name in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("data/opti.csv")
df03 = df.loc[df["%"]==0.3]
df04 = df.loc[df["%"]==0.4]
df06 = df.loc[df["%"]==0.6]
df08 = df.loc[df["%"]==0.8]
df1 = df.loc[df["%"]==1]
x = np.array([0.3,0.4,0.6,0.8,1])
e = np.array([np.std(df03),np.std(df04),np.std(df06),np.std(df08),np.std(df1)])

df.head(5)
df["Tablettenmasse"]
```

[df Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAnSv.png)

When I write df["Tablettenmasse"] I get a key error. But when I select the column with iloc it works. Why isn´t it working the normal way?

edit: as mosc9575 suggested, there was a space before the word. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, please write your code as text instead of an image. It helps us to copy/paste your code.

Comment: Try to print the columns using `df.columns`, I guesse there is some whitespace (Leerzeichen) somewhere.